# Install IPA distribution via iTunes but app not run?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, ipa

1. I archive an IPA file using distribution provisioning profile
2. I drag IPA to iTunes and connect my iPhone and install it
3. But i can't run app after install

Can you help me!

Comment: Any error you received ?

Comment: Have you registered that devices UDID with the distribution profile ?

Comment: it is difficiult to say which step you missed. I would suggest you to watch youtube instead https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zayH93Gk-Ow and please get aquainted with testflightapp.com. Otherwise there might be a run time error if everything's fine with building process.

Answer (score 2):

You have to create **`ADHOC distribution profile`**, and include your **`DeviceUDID`** and then make **`IPA`** using the **`ADHOC Profile`** will make the app run. If you have signed it using just the Distribution Profile, it will not run because its for **`iTunes Store`**, not for simple installation.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Does the app start and terminate immediately? If so there is an issue with your code signing. Maybe you chose the wrong signing identity or your device is not linked to the distribution profile.